# PowerShell - API data into XML

Tags: powershell

I am new to powershell and trying to write my first script.I am using PowerShell v2.0. I have the following script that makes an API call and gets data into `$data` variable.

```
$FullURL = $url1+$url2+$Url3
$client = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$data = $client.DownloadString($FullURL)
Set-Content -Value $data -Path 'c:\API.txt'
```

`$data` outputs the below (example). Note - gettype() results are string. -

```
<attribute name="Business Unit">Platform</attribute>
<attribute name="Department">Channels Technology</attribute>
<attribute name="Team">Stackexchange</attribute>
<attribute name="Environment">World</attribute>
<attribute name="ServerModel">Synology</attribute>
<attribute name="datacentre">New York</attribute>
<attribute name="Application">PowerShell Teacher</attribute>
<attribute name="Description">Learn How To Use PowerShell</attribute>
```

I need to get the above into the below sample of the XML file, in between the attributes tags -

```
 <selfAnnounce>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <retryInterval>60</retryInterval>
        <requireReverseConnection>false</requireReverseConnection>
        <probeName>
            <hostname/>
            <data>_</data>
            <port/>
            <data>-SA</data>
        </probeName>
        <managedEntity>
            <name></name>
            <attributes>
            </attributes>
```

I am not sure where to begin with this one. I thought it would be something like the below but the results are all in one tag, maybe because they are not pscustom objects -

```
[xml]$XML = Get-Content $SelfannounceXMLEdit
$data | ForEach-Object {
$tempchild = $XML.CreateElement("Attributename")
$tempchild.set_InnerText($_)
$newType = $XML.netprobe.selfAnnounce.managedEntity.attributes.AppendChild($tempchild)
}
$XML.Save($SelfannounceXMLEdit)
```

This gives the following results which is obviously wrong for an XML file-

```
 <attributes>
 <Attributename><attribute name="Business Unit">Platform</attribute> <attribute name="Department">Channels Technology</attribute> <attribute name="Team">Stackexchange</attribute> <attribute name="Environment">World</attribute> <attribute name="ServerModel">Synology</attribute> <attribute name="datacentre">New York</attribute> <attribute name="Application">PowerShell Teacher</attribute> <attribute name="Description">Learn How To User PowerShell</attribute></Attributename> 
  </attributes>
```

Results should look like the following -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<netprobe compatibility="1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://google.com/netprobe.xsd">
  <selfAnnounce>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <retryInterval>10</retryInterval>
    <requireReverseConnection>false</requireReverseConnection>
    <probeName>
      <hostname />
      <data>_</data>
      <port />
      <data>-SA</data>
    </probeName>
    <managedEntity>
      <name></name>
      <attributes>
        <attribute name="Business Unit">Platform</attribute> 
        <attribute name="Department">Channels Technology</attribute> 
        <attribute name="Team">Stackexchange</attribute> 
      </attributes>
      <types>
        <type>Core</type>
        <type>Core Windows</type>
        <!--Autogenerated types-->
        <!--End of Autogenerated types-->
      </types>
    </managedEntity>
    <gateways>
      <gateway>
        <hostname>MFT556</hostname>
        <port>1234</port>
      </gateway>
    </gateways>
  </selfAnnounce>
</netprobe>
```

Please help me resolve this issue. I have tried converting $data into xml but keep getting errors. I have tried exporting the API as XML but get errors. any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please include valid xml-samples next time. Missing lots of elements here.

Comment: Hi Frode F, apologies, I have updated the post to show full XML file. Thank you

Comment: They are just showing and example of what the result would look like. The XML is a template and would not have any attributes. An API call gets the attributes of the host which I then need to import into XML.

Comment: Yeah, noticed that. It was the wrong sample being updated (the unmodified one is still wrong), so it took a few seconds. :-)  Try my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can't modify an element type AFAIK, so the `AttributeName`-node is useless.
- `...managedEntity.attributes` is empty, which means dot-accesing it will return an empty string which doesn't have a `AppendChild()`

I would create an xml-document for each string from the API and import the `attribute` node to the "real" xml-file and append it. Remember to use ex `SelectSingleNode()` to actually get the `attributes`-node, especially the first time when it's empty. Try:

```
[xml]$XML = Get-Content $SelfannounceXMLEdit
($data -split "`n") | Where-Object { $_.Trim() } | ForEach-Object {
    #Create XMLdocument for <attribute name="foo">bar</attribute>
    $tempchild = [xml]$_.Trim()

    #Import the attribute-node in the temp xmldocument to the "real" document context
    $attribute = $xml.ImportNode($tempchild.attribute, $true)

    #Append attribute-node
    $newType = $XML.netprobe.selfAnnounce.managedEntity.selectsinglenode("attributes").AppendChild($attribute)
}
$XML.Save($SelfannounceXMLEdit)
```

Comment: Try updated answer. Forgot that you didn't read `$data` from a file, so we need to split it on newline to get one attribute at a time inside the loop.  Btw. answers should not be edited. Small errors can be posted in the comments, big code blocks/error messages should be added as an update to the question.

Comment: Hi Frodo, Thank for the tips. still a newbie to StackExchange and you have been very helpful. That seems to be working however i get the following error message - Cannot convert value "" to type "System.Xml.XmlDocument". Error: "Root element is missing." and the last attribute gets added twice. Any ideas? Error is reffering to $tempchild = [xml]$_

Comment: You're getting blank values after splitting. Probably a linebreak (CR) as I only split on LF. Try updated answer.

Comment: Your a genius Frodo F, no errors, no duplicates, works amazing. I am going to try and decipher this and learn from it. Thank you again.